# Can use a android phone as a pc to write c,lisp,java.....and compile the code to run it?

Tags: android, ide, lisp

I have an Android phone (Motorola Milestone) and I want to set it as a small PC on my hand. I want to use it for programming, such as write a lisp or C `helloworld` program, compile the code and run it.

Is there a C, lisp, Java, ruby, etc. development environment available for Android OS?

For example, Turbo C, clisp, Python, Perl; any language dev IDE for Android OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Project](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting) supports some of your requirements but you can expect new languages soon.

I'm pretty sure there's no IDE available for Android (...yet! ;)

Comment: a IDE is not naccesary... I just want a compiler and run-env on android... such as CLISP for android...I'm learning lisp right now...I take my phone with me every time, so I wonder if there be some programming tool on android can let me to do programming...

Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

i believe there might be some IDE for compiling C, Perl, etc. for android around; because i'm using one called Pascal for android to edit and compile some simple pascal code.

the pascal IDE that i'm using on my android is here:
https://market.android.com/details?id=me.zed_0xff.android.pascal&feature=search_result

this is another IDE for Ruby running on Android, it lets you edit your ruby code on android, however, it calls online service for compilation:
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.idedroidfree&feature=search_result

for C++, i just can't find out on android market, if anyone digs out such thing on android market, please let me know also

Answer (score 1):

You can use [C4Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc&hl=en) for compiling C language.

I have been using another program called [**Termux**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en)

Install the app and run

```
apt install ruby
```

It will install Ruby inside that terminal. Now you can cd to your sdcard and run the ruby file using the terminal.

*It doesn't require root*
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

so far i know of a java compiler called JavaNide, it supports writing of java code and compilation and also the development of android apps.I have used it to develop android apps but the pnly issue is that most of the apps ,intended for android dev on phone dont support gradle system and also when coding java,the apps don't support java graphics library....but generally this apps play  a huge role in sharpening your skills

Here is the link for accessing the java app on play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duy.compiler.javanide

Also there is a C ide on playstore: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.cxxdroid

Enjoy